# Save context state in Noesis Javascript.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-3, javascript.net

I'm using the noesis [javascript.net library](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net) in my C# MVC3 application.

Is it possible to save a snapshot of a javascript context object and then reload that snapshot into a new javascript context instance?

Comment: I have a feeling this will not be possible, but you could try using serialization

Comment: I just tried it, and sadly it did not work.  It was a good idea though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the original user will find this useful but I achieved this by adding a object to my context that let me write to disk (simple wrapper around TextWriter), then serialized `this` where `this` was the global scope so it captured all objects.
The obvious pitfall is that not all objects are serialized proper (I used `JSON.stringify` for serialization).
When I need to reload the context I loaded up the string from the file into a variable in my context and set the objects back.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if you'd see this by now.  I was able to serialize 'This' perfectly but I'm having difficulty in getting it to parse back into a new javascript context.   

JavascriptContext.Run("var xxx = JSON.parse(\"" + simplejson + "\");");

Is the line I"m attempting to get it back into the javascript context..but how would I set it all to 'this' also?

Comment: I was able to get it to parse, but now I can't see a way to set that object to the global namespace in the javascript...is that even possible?

Comment: This is purely off the top of my head, but if you were to do something like `for (var i in deserializedObj){ this[i] = deserializedObj[i]; }`
As I don't think simply setting `this = deserializedObj` will work. You just have to make sure that code gets executed in the context required.